# superuser not creating TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: django, django-models

when i run createsuperuser command ..it ask's me to enter email and then password .After entering password it doesn't create super user instead it gives me TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'.

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db) 
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user



class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD= 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = 'name'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Comment: Why do you have a custom user in the first place here?

Comment: I was following some tutorials and they used custom user model...Can you suggest me the solution?

Comment: You shouldn't need to override `create_user`/`create_superuser` since you inherit from the base manager.